# Is there any way we can get r-square value dynamically or using loop if we have so many csv files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I have 200 to 220 csv files and I want to calculate r-square value for each csv file,and I have every time open csv file and calculate r-square and again open another csv file.
Here is my code  I am using :

```
import pandas
import scipy
import numpy
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
url = "file1.csv"
dataframe = pandas.read_csv(url)
dataframe
array=dataframe.values
X=array[:,4:5]
Y=array[:,3:4]
scalerx = RobustScaler()
x_scaled = scalerx.fit_transform(X)
x_scaled

scalery = RobustScaler()
y_scaled = scalery.fit_transform(Y)
y_scaled

a=x_scaled
b=y_scaled

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
linreg=LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(a,b)
#LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
print linreg.intercept_
#[ 0.30611686]
print linreg.coef_
#[[-0.21568568]]
y_pred=linreg.predict(a)
r2=linreg.score(a,b)
print(r2)
```

this is my code save in overall.py 
then I have run this command in command prompt  : $python overall.py then I have get r2 value for single csv file data. then again I need o use file2.csv , file3.csv,....so on, any hints how to get r-square at the same time for all csv files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code in a function and run function over multiple files. E.g.:

```
import os

for f in os.listdir(os.curdir):
   if f.endswith('.csv'):
       my_function(f)
```

So in your case:

```
import os
import pandas
import scipy
import numpy
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler

def my_function(url):

    dataframe = pandas.read_csv(url)
    dataframe
    array=dataframe.values
    X=array[:,4:5]
    Y=array[:,3:4]
    scalerx = RobustScaler()
    x_scaled = scalerx.fit_transform(X)
    x_scaled

    scalery = RobustScaler()
    y_scaled = scalery.fit_transform(Y)
    y_scaled

    a=x_scaled
    b=y_scaled

    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    linreg=LinearRegression()
    linreg.fit(a,b)
    #LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
    print linreg.intercept_
    #[ 0.30611686]
    print linreg.coef_
    #[[-0.21568568]]
    y_pred=linreg.predict(a)
    r2=linreg.score(a,b)
    print(r2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for f in os.listdir(os.curdir):
       if f.endswith('.csv'):
           my_function(f)
```

Comment: there no need to use file name?  e.g file1.csv ...file220,csv? and this code use before dataframe line ?

Comment: your filename will be stored in the variable 'f', which you pass as an argument to a function. If this is not obvious I would recommend reading about it a bit more: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function

Comment: I also edited the answer to include exemplar code. You might consider leaving out some stuff outside etc., but given your code was meant to be run over one file it should do the job.

Comment: I get TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be: for f in os.listdir(os.curdir) since os.curdir is a string not a method. I will correct it in the code.